# Problem with Rectangle.Contains method

Tags: c#, winforms, contains

i built a space invaders game, and the problem is , that the hit sensitivity is way too sensitive. Here is how i trace whether the player was hit.

```
 bool playersWasShot=false;
 foreach (var shotsInvader in Invadershots)
 {    // below is the Area representing the image size. and the location of the invaders shot
      if(playership.Area.Contains(shotsInvader.Location))
      {
           //player was shot game over.
           playersWasShot=true;
           break;
      }
 }
```

The area property from the PlayerShip class:

```
// move simply updates the position of the ship on the x-axis as i move the ship.
// as you can guess. the second variable represents the size of the picture

Area =new Rectangle(new Point(move,900), Properties.Resources.player.Size);
```

The shot location property in the Shots class is being updated as the shot travels to the 
player..

```
// the shot, travels to the player on the y-axis only
Location=new Point(Location.X, invaderShotLocation);
```

i checked in the debugger when the game is over..and this is what i got:

This line:

```
if(playership.Area.Contains(shotsInvader.Location))
{
//i put a debugging point inside this if statment!!!
}
```

represents info on the ship:

```
player Area {X=90,Y=900,Width=54,Height=33}
Location    {X=60,Y=900}
```

represents info on the invaders shot:

```
Location {X=140,Y=900}
```

The shot didnt even go inside the players ship..how come

```
        public static Bitmap SHIP = Properties.Resources.player;
    public Point Location;
    public int move=10;
    public Rectangle Area { set { } get { return new Rectangle(new Point(move, 900), Properties.Resources.player.Size); } }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
```

Those are the 2 methods in the ship class that govern all the movement and the drawing

```
        if (game.Alive) //checks if the player is alive.
        {
             // draws the SHIP picture. 900 is a fixed field..thats where the ship is
             // it is on the y axis that never changes.. x-axis do change..depending
          // on where i move the ship to.
                 g.DrawImage(SHIP, move, 900); 
                Location = new Point(move, 900); 
        }
        else
        {

            g.DrawImage(SHIP, move, 900, SHIP.Width, SHIP.Height);
            Location = new Point(move, 900);
        }
    }



    public void Move(Direction d)
    {

        switch (d)
        {
```

// an enum is passed when i press the arrows indicating to move left or right
                case Direction.LEFT:  move -= 10; break;
                case Direction.RIGHT: move += 10; break; 
            }
            Area = new Rectangle(new Point(move, 900), SHIP.Size);
        }

NOTE= SAME LOGIC WAS APPLIED WHEN AN INVADER IS BEING HIT BY THE PLAYER, AND THE INVADER DOES DISAPPEAR ONLY WHEN THE SHOT HITS HIM

Bug found in the Shot class. the players and invaders shots share:

..i found the bug. it was in the shot class. i modified it now. issue has been solved

Comment: `Properties.Resources.player` is a very slow call.  You should store the bitmaps in `static readonly` fields; this will make your program _much_ faster.

Comment: Is it to do with absolute or relative co-ordinates?

Comment: Question text is misleading, this has nothing to do with LINQ - you are using `Rectangle.Contains()`

Comment: i put the picture size in a static property..still the ship gets hit too fast..

Comment: i think it does, Broken. i got confused. i used LINQ before hand. i thought it was LINQS method. it is a triangle..correction needed

Comment: Not to whine about not getting rep or anything :) but why is this question marked "community wiki"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the shot did go into the ship. The shot is at (140, 900) and the ship's Area corners are at (90, 900) and (144, 900). (140, 900) is inside of that.

What is the "Location    {X=60,Y=900}" part listed after the ship's Area listing? Are you perhaps painting the ship in a different spot than the hit test Area?

Comment: i updated my answer. a game over is declared..way way before the shot reaches the player

Comment: I don't understand. Are the coordinates you posted for when the game ends? It seems like that makes sense because the shot is inside the Area.

Comment: it does..but the shot doesnt appear on the screen. i cant see it :(

Comment: @Dmitry: If you can't see the shot, there's probably a bug in your drawing method.

Comment: i think i found where the bug is. it is in the shot class. the drawing method...Location=new Point(Location.X, invaderShotLocation);
invaderShot is always set to 900.. which is the line where the player is... it travels somehow successfully. but once it is above the player it is game over. i looked through all the invader shots all of them have the variable Location=new Point(Location.X, invaderShotLocation); //invaderShotLocation set as 900.. i wonder why?? i accidently discovered this bug. and i am trying to fix it now

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a bug in `PlayerShip.Area.Contains`.  Double check the logic.

Comment: But how do you explain the shot coordinates? they arent in the ships area

Comment: The used the same method on the invader.(to identify if the invader was shot by the player..and it works...)